# When submit button is Clicked on the final page I need a center display wording "Thank you for your time", and image of a green cheek mark included

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I have finished making a survey page which is based purely on HTML and jQuery. Now the next part is when the submit button is clicked I need everything to become hidden and the only display should show is simple HTML code in bold wording "Thank you for you time" with image.

Here's my code so for...

```
@foreach (var i in Model)
{

        if (i.Question_Type == "DROPDOWN")
        {

        <div class="container text-center">


            <div class="row idrow" data-questions="@counter">
                @{counter++;
                }

                <div id="question1" class="form-group">
                    <label class="lab text-center" for="form-group-select">
                        @i.Question_Order @Html.Raw(@i.Question)
                    </label>
                    @{ var works = "question" + counter.ToString();}
                    <select name="@works" class="form-control selects" id="form-group-select">
                        @for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); x++)
                        {
                            var t = x - 1;
                            if (i.qOps != null)
                            {
                                <option> @i.qOps.options[t]</option>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <option> @x</option>

                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        }


        if (i.Question_Type == "RADIO")
        {




        <div class="container">
            <div class="row idrow" data-questions="@counter">
                @{counter++;
                }
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="lab" for="questions">
                        @i.Question_Order @i.Question
                    </label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div id="question1" class="radio-inline">
                                @for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); x++)
                                {
                                    var t = x - 1;
                                    if (i.qOps != null)
                                    {
                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="question"> @i.qOps.options[t]</label>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" min="0" max="@x" name="question"></label>

                                    }
                                }
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        }
        if (i.Question_Type == "CHECKBOX")
        {
        for (int y = 1; y <= Convert.ToInt32(i.Question_SubType); y++)
        {
        @*<div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <label>@y</label>   <input type="checkbox" name="question">

                </div>
            </div>*@
        }
        }

        }
       <div class="container ">
    <div class="azibsButtons">
        <button type="button" id="previous" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Prev</button>

        <button type="button" id="next" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>

        <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="Sendingitoff();" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>

    </div>

</div>
<div id="final">
    Thank you for your time 

</div>



        <script>
            function formToJSON() {
                var form = {};
                $('.selects').each(function () {
                    var self = $(this);
                    var name = self.attr('name');
                    if (form[name]) {
                        form[name] = form[name] + ',' + self.val();
                    }
                    else {
                        form[name] = self.val();
                    }
                });

                return form;
            }



            function Sendingitoff() {
               // debugger;
                var form = formToJSON();
                var look = JSON.stringify(form);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Answers", "GSSurvey")/' + '?username=@Request.QueryString["username"]' + '&receiverid=@Request.QueryString["receiverid"]' + '&id=@Request.QueryString["id"]',

                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: look,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {



                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });

            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                ShowTheelement(0);
                $("#previous").addClass('hidden');
                $("#submit").addClass('hidden');


                var dataVal = 0;

                $("#next").click(function () {
                    dataVal++;
                    $("#previous").removeClass('hidden');
                    dataVal == $(".idrow[data-questions]").length - 1 ? $(this).addClass('hidden') : $(this).removeClass('hidden');
                    ShowTheelement(dataVal);
                    if (dataVal == $(".idrow[data-questions]").length -1 ) { 
                        $("#submit").removeClass('hidden');
                    }


                });

                $("#previous").click(function () {
                    dataVal--;
                    $("#next").removeClass('hidden');
                    dataVal == 0 ? $(this).addClass('hidden') : $(this).removeClass('hidden');
                    ShowTheelement(dataVal);
                    if (dataVal == $(".idrow[data-questions]").length - 2)
                        $("#submit").addClass('hidden');



                });
            });

            function ShowTheelement(dataVal) {
                $(".idrow").addClass('hidden');
                $(".idrow[data-questions='" + dataVal + "']").removeClass('hidden');

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I suggest using [this alert style](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp), very easy to implement. Place it inside of your `$.ajax({...success: ... {...}...});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to show the div with id *final*, in a way it takes up everything.
You could just make this div start hidden (give it the existing class *hidden*) and after form submission show it, overlapping above the rest (like a modal).

One way to do it would be:

1. Create a css class for the *final* div

   ```
   .overlay {
    position:fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
   }
   ```
2. Hide it by default

   ```
   <div id="final" class="hidden"> Thank you for your time </div>
   ```
3. Then, after the success of your ajax call:

   ```
   success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    /*do what you need with the data*/
    $("#final").addClass('overlay');
   }
   ```

   Remember this will take up all of your screen so you should consider a timer to close it or a close button to hide it.

Comment: .overlay class, does that need to be called in html? or just where it is in css right now?. And iv'e been trying to use my image which is in my desktop but its basically coming up image less like a null type of image

Comment: You need to create the overlay class on your page's CSS file. As for the image, I don't see it inside the *final* div. Whre is the markup for it? Also, it should be on the project's folder, not on your desktop.

Comment: Ok. i took care of the image part. But now after implementing all the and then going all the way to the submit button and clicking it, does nothing yet. is the class not showing?

Comment: Inspect the element with the browser's web tools and also check for console errors. Can you do a plunker or a jsfiddle of what you have, so we can see exactly what is happening?